# When I change of UIView my NavigationBar doesn't

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, background-image

I have a ViewController embedded in a NavigationController whose I customize the NavigationBar (changing the background image in the code), and when I click on a button it leads the user to another view correctly. But, I can't change the image of the NavBar when I reach this view...
I tried to write this :

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"otherBackground.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

In the IBAction method, in ViewDidUnload of my main ViewController and in ViewDidLoad and initWithNibName of my other ViewController, but nothing changes the previous image. What can I do ?

My IBAction is the following :

```
- (IBAction) versModeEmploi : (id) sender
{
    if(!modeEmploi) modeEmploi = [[ModeEmploiController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ModeEmploiController" bundle:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Retour" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:modeEmploi animated:NO];
}
```

Thanks a lot for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your first view controller:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work... And I've noticed an odd thing. In my opinion the navigationBar properties change but it is not repainted. Because I also have a little "Dark Info" button on my main view (that's the configuration you've by default when you created a new Utility Application), when I click on it, the main view flips to another one and when I come back on the main view the navigation Bar background has changed...

Comment: I'm almost done with this problem ! I use the setNeedsDisplay method and it works. Almost. I'm just facing a little issue with my BackBarButton to redraw the initial navbar.

Answer (score 1):

Very stupid question (aka, "did you try to turn it off and on again?"):

How did you transition from the "embedded view" to the second view? It should look something like this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

If not, then `self.navigationController` won't point to anything usefull in your second view.

Regards,
Chris

Comment: Look at my Edit on my main post, thanks a lot for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

Well if anyone is interested in the solution, I just had to use this to solve the problem :

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setNeedsDisplay];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This is to add in viewDidAppear/Disappear methods depending on what we want.